# Javascript to linkify string in "minutes:seconds" format

Tags: javascript, video, seek, linkify

I have a video site where people can comment under each video.

I'm trying to create a linkify function that will parse a user's comment and look for substrings in the "minutes:seconds" format. The link will have a click event that will trigger a function call, which in turn will seek the video to that particular moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What exactly do you need assistance with?  Brief tip:  For searching for substrings in the minutes:seconds format, you'll probably want to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: I've already tried something involving indexOf. It was ugly and buggy. I'm asking here because I know regex would be the best way to go about this and I'm not very good at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started (you'll have to tweak the regular expression to validate the time correctly):

```
function linkify(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/, "<span onclick='video($1, $2)'>$1:$2</span>");
}

function video(mins, seconds) {
    mins = window.parseInt(mins, 10);
    seconds = window.parseInt(seconds, 10);   

    // Do the stuff with the video
}

console.log(linkify("Look at the video at 01:23 for something interesting"));
```

Comment: This is definitely a good start but ideally, the code shouldn't assume there will be 2 digits each. For example:
    1:1
    1:01
    1:10
    10:10
    123:10
should all be considered as valid.

Comment: How about the following regex: `/(\d+):([0-5][0-9])/g`? This will allow any number of digits followed by 0-59 for seconds. I've also added in the `g` flag so that *all* times are matched (rather than just the first).

Comment: _Almost_. This would still fail if the "seconds" part is only one digit, i.e 1:1. I need both 1:1 and 1:01 to be valid.

Comment: How about this: `/(\d+):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])/g`? This is a good website to play around with regular expressions: [http://gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)